# Перевод из экспоненциальной записи числа в обычную

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста как перевести число типа 7,8910E-008 в следующую запись 0.00000007891.
Числа находятся в стринге; желательно использовать DecimalFormat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("7.8910E-008")).toPlainString()
```